# MVC url shortener

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-shortener

I would like to write a URL shortener using MVC routing.
The thing is that I'd like to use the following URL: {host}/?{word}

To do that I use the MapRoute method to have the default go to the correct controller. and it does, but when it passes null to the parameter instead of the content of {word}.

The same thing works correctly if I specify the parameter name, i.e. 
{host}/?{param-name}={word}

Does anyone know how can I tell MVC that if I don't specify the parameter name then it should go to the first, or a default param?

Comment: Since '?' denotes the end of the virtual path, you may have issues. You may be able to hack something together by making your own model binder. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584

Comment: The problem is "?" signifies a query string so the parser isn't going to know how to pull "word" out. You would have to revise your route to be {host}/{word} OR perhaps in your controller action access the Request.Querystring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to write action filter that you put on your action method. Action filter should go trough url query parameters, if it finds parameter with empty value it can bind to parameter.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null) {
    NameValueCollection urlQuery = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query);

    for (int i = 0; i < urlQuery.Keys.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (urlQuery.Get(urlQuery[i]) == null)
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters["word"] = urlQuery[i];
        }
    }
}
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

}

You must write some not null conditions so it doesn't fail miserably :)

**Edit:**
If you want to drop ? just use default mvc url routing, something like this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UrlShortener", // Route name
    "{word}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "UrlShortener", action = "Fetch",  word="Default", }
```

);

your Controller will accept

```
public ActionResult UrlShortener(string word) {
if (word == "Default") return Content("No word specified");

//some BLL
return View();
```

}

That way your url will be http://hostname/word , if word is not specified it passes "Default".

If that is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks! that works. is there a way to lose the '?', or that would be asking too much? :)

Comment: @AdamOren np. I edited the answer so I can put some code in it :). I hope that I understood you correctly.

Comment: I mean that instead of writing {host}/?{word} I would like to write {host}/{word}

Comment: If you mean in MapRoute you don't have to write {host}/?{word}. For first example you can just write {host} because routing engine doesn't work with ?.So you can use urls like http://hostname/host/?bla. You can even combine two methods so you can use urls with http://hostname/host/bla and http://hostname/host/?bla

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, so let me try again: I would like to support URLs like hostname/bla instead of hostname/?bla

Comment: The code in edit section of answer will allow you that. Just copy/paste MapRoute in global.cs (imortant, before DefaultRoute) and you even without that custom action filter you can have urls like, http://site.com/bla  and http://site.com/bla2, instead http://site.com/?bla

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10411/discussion-between-goran-zuri-and-adam-oren)